# flutter - make dynamic mark event in calendar plugin

Tags: flutter, events, dart, calendar, widget

I want to mark the event once every `4 days`.

example today is the `1st`, mark the event will be available on the `5th`, `10th`, `15th`, `20th`, `25th`, `30th`, etc.

if today is the `3rd`, the event will be available on the `8th`, `13th`, `18th`, etc.

**how does that function work?**

I use this calendar plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel

Following is the function to mark event manually:

```
EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>();

   build(){
       _calendarCarouselNoHeader = CalendarCarousel<Event>(
       ...
       markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
       ...
       ),
    }

 @override
  void initState() {

     _markedDateMap.add(
         new DateTime(2020, 2, 26),
        new Event(
         date: new DateTime(2020, 2, 26),
         title: 'Event 5',
         icon: _eventIcon,
         ));

     _markedDateMap.add(
         new DateTime(2020, 2, 26),
        new Event(
         date: new DateTime(2020, 2, 26),
         title: 'Event 5',
         icon: _eventIcon,
         ));

    super.initState();
}
```

**Any anwser will appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
working demo show when pass start date time with

```
addMarker(DateTime(2020, 2, 01));
addMarker(DateTime(2020, 2, 03));
```

code snippet

```
addMarker(DateTime startEventDateTime) {

    var eventDateTime = startEventDateTime;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      if(eventDateTime.day == 1) {
        eventDateTime = eventDateTime.add(Duration(days: (4)));
      } else {
        eventDateTime = eventDateTime.add(Duration(days: (5)));
      }
      print(eventDateTime.toLocal());
      _markedDateMap.add(
          eventDateTime,
          Event(
            date: eventDateTime,
            title: 'Event $i',
            icon: _eventIcon,
          ));

    }
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart'
    show CalendarCarousel;
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event_list.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show DateFormat;

void main() => runApp( MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      title: 'dooboolab flutter calendar',
      theme:  ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:  MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Calendar Carousel Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() =>  _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime(2020, 2, 17);
  DateTime _currentDate2 = DateTime(2020, 2, 17);
  String _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(DateTime(2020, 2, 17));
  DateTime _targetDateTime = DateTime(2020, 2, 17);
//  List<DateTime> _markedDate = [DateTime(2018, 9, 20), DateTime(2018, 10, 11)];
  static Widget _eventIcon =  Container(
    decoration:  BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1000)),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
    child:  Icon(
      Icons.person,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  );

  EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = EventList<Event>();
  CalendarCarousel _calendarCarousel, _calendarCarouselNoHeader;

  @override
  void initState() {
   addMarker(DateTime(2020, 2, 03));
    super.initState();
  }

  addMarker(DateTime startEventDateTime) {

    var eventDateTime = startEventDateTime;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      if(eventDateTime.day == 1) {
        eventDateTime = eventDateTime.add(Duration(days: (4)));
      } else {
        eventDateTime = eventDateTime.add(Duration(days: (5)));
      }
      print(eventDateTime.toLocal());
      _markedDateMap.add(
          eventDateTime,
          Event(
            date: eventDateTime,
            title: 'Event $i',
            icon: _eventIcon,
          ));

    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Example with custom icon
    _calendarCarousel = CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate = date);
        events.forEach((event) => print(event.title));
      },
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
//          weekDays: null, /// for pass null when you do not want to render weekDays
      headerText: 'Custom Header',
//          markedDates: _markedDate,
      weekFormat: true,
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      height: 200.0,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate2,
      showIconBehindDayText: true,
//          daysHaveCircularBorder: false, /// null for not rendering any border, true for circular border, false for rectangular border
      customGridViewPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      markedDateShowIcon: true,
      markedDateIconMaxShown: 2,
      selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      markedDateIconBuilder: (event) {
        return event.icon;
      },
      minSelectedDate: _currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: 360)),
      maxSelectedDate: _currentDate.add(Duration(days: 360)),
      todayButtonColor: Colors.transparent,
      todayBorderColor: Colors.green,
      markedDateMoreShowTotal:
      false, // null for not showing hidden events indicator
//          markedDateIconMargin: 9,
//          markedDateIconOffset: 3,
    );

    /// Example Calendar Carousel without header and custom prev & next button
    _calendarCarouselNoHeader = CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      todayBorderColor: Colors.green,
      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate2 = date);
        events.forEach((event) => print(event.title));
      },
      daysHaveCircularBorder: true,
      showOnlyCurrentMonthDate: false,
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
      weekFormat: false,
//      firstDayOfWeek: 4,
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      height: 420.0,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate2,
      targetDateTime: _targetDateTime,
      customGridViewPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      markedDateCustomShapeBorder: CircleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow)
      ),
      markedDateCustomTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      showHeader: false,
      // markedDateIconBuilder: (event) {
      //   return Container(
      //     color: Colors.blue,
      //   );
      // },
      todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      todayButtonColor: Colors.yellow,
      selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      minSelectedDate: _currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: 360)),
      maxSelectedDate: _currentDate.add(Duration(days: 360)),
      prevDaysTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      ),
      inactiveDaysTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.tealAccent,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
      onCalendarChanged: (DateTime date) {
        this.setState(() {
          _targetDateTime = date;
          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
        });
      },
      onDayLongPressed: (DateTime date) {
        print('long pressed date $date');
      },
    );

    return  Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              //custom icon
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: _calendarCarousel,
              ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
              //custom icon without header
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 30.0,
                  bottom: 16.0,
                  left: 16.0,
                  right: 16.0,
                ),
                child:  Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          _currentMonth,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                          ),
                        )),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('PREV'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _targetDateTime = DateTime(_targetDateTime.year, _targetDateTime.month -1);
                          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('NEXT'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _targetDateTime = DateTime(_targetDateTime.year, _targetDateTime.month +1);
                          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: _calendarCarouselNoHeader,
              ), //
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its works
But, when i use DateTime.now() for startEventDateTime, marked date does not work?

Comment: please use addMarker(DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day)); I have tested, it works fine.

Comment: @chunhunghan could you please help me to change the border color according to the event type? I added a type in Event modal, according to that type the circle of the event will be customized?

Comment: @Farhana, you may need to revise https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_calendar_carousel/blob/03437596c9de5f971bc05115236f0750ae22bc73/lib/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart#L433

Comment: @chunhunghan I revised and try to customize but still not able to do it.